# Converting unsigned chars to float in assembly (to prepare for float vector calculations)

Tags: assembly, sse2

I am trying to optimize a function using SSE2.  I'm wondering if I can prepare the data for my assembly code better than this way.  My source data is a bunch of unsigned chars from pSrcData.  I copy it to this array of floats, as my calculation needs to happen in float.

```
unsigned char *pSrcData = GetSourceDataPointer();

__declspec(align(16)) float vVectX[4];

vVectX[0] = (float)pSrcData[0];
vVectX[1] = (float)pSrcData[2];
vVectX[2] = (float)pSrcData[4];
vVectX[3] = (float)pSrcData[6];

__asm 
{
     movaps xmm0, [vVectX]
     [...]  // do some floating point calculations on float vectors using addps, mulps, etc
}
```

Is there a quicker way for me to cast every other byte of pSrcData to a float and store it into vVectX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) AND with a mask to zero out the odd bytes (`PAND`)

(2) Unpack from 16 bits to 32 bits (`PUNPCKLWD` with a zero vector)

(3) Convert 32 bit ints to floats (`CVTDQ2PS`)

Three instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Super old thread I realise, but I was searching for code myself to do this. This is my solution, which I think is simpler:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef __AVX__
// Modified from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031149/speedup-a-short-to-float-cast
// Convert unsigned 8 bit integer to  float. Length must be multiple of 8
int  avxu8tof32(uint8_t *src, float *dest, int length) {
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<length; i+= 8) {

    //  Load 8 8-bit int into the low half of a 128 register
    __m128i v = _mm_loadl_epi64 ((__m128i const*)(src+i));

    //  Convert to 32-bit integers
    __m256i v32 = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(v);

    //  Convert to float
    __m256 vf = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps (v32);

    //  Store
    _mm256_store_ps(dest + i,vf);
  }
  return(0);
}
#endif
```

However benchmarking shows it no faster than just looping over the array in C, with compiler optimisation enabled. Maybe the approach will be more useful as the initial stage of a bunch of AVX computations.

Comment: The OP only wants every *other* `uint8_t` as a `float`.  With AVX2, probably the best be is an `__m128i` `_mm_and_si128` and then `_mm256_cvtepu16_epi32` on that.  Or if you're going to later pack back to `uint8_t`, maybe a 256b `and` and then unpack lo/hi (against zero) in-lane to go from 16b to 32b integer elements before conversion to FP.  That avoids any lane-crossing shuffles (like `vpmovzx ymm`), and will avoid needing the inverse shuffle for packing again.

Comment: And yes, you'd want to do this on the fly before something you manually vectorized.  Compilers can auto-vectorize simple copy+convert loops.

Comment: Thanks Peter - I missed that entirely