# Speedup a short to float cast?

Tags: c++, x86, type-conversion, sse

I have a short to float cast in C++ that is bottlenecking my code.

The code translates from a hardware device buffer which is natively shorts, this represents the input from a fancy photon counter.

```
float factor=  1.0f/value;
for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i++)//25% of time is spent doing this
{
    int value = source[i];//ushort -> int
    destination[i] = value*factor;//int*float->float
}
```

**A few details**

1. Value should go from 0 to 2^16-1, it represents the pixel values of a highly sensitive camera
2. I'm on a multicore x86 machine with an i7 processor (i7 960 which is SSE 4.2 and 4.1).
3. Source is aligned to an 8 bit boundary (a requirement of the hardware device)
4. W*H is always divisible by 8, most of the time W and H are divisible by 8

This makes me sad, is there anything I can do about it?

I am using Visual Studios 2012...

Comment: Are source and destination both `short` ? Or is destination `float` ? Can you assume x86 (and therefore SSE) ? What is the possible range of values for `value` ?

Comment: Besides `destination[]`, what is the type and range of `value`?

Comment: Have you looked at the code, does it not use SSE already? I know `gcc` will unroll loops like this to use SSE to calculate multiple values at once.

Comment: Ok, seems like the compiler doesn't generate SSE for this case. I will see if I can come up with something using inline assembler.

Comment: @PaulR No, the source is a ushort and the destination is a float.

Comment: There is no **cast** in this code. The comments indicate that there are some **conversions**, but there is not enough code to see what conversions are being done. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**.

Comment: What is the range of factor is it 0<factor<=1? I mean is value always >=1?  This bounty does not end for 4 days!

Comment: Actually the factor is always less then 1. It is inverse of the maximum number of bits. The purpose to scale our number from 0 to 1. A common value is `1/(2**16 -1)`.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you put that in the description.  How big can W*H be?

Comment: @raxman W*H correspond to 5 mega-pixel image of size 2560 x 1920...

Comment: I posted my answer.  I have the fastest results. My code is not restricted to SSE4.2 it automatically uses AVX if available without changing the code.  Additionally, my code works even when W*H is not a multiple of 16 (unlike some other code).  Unless someone finds a significant improvement I believe I deserve to win the bounty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a basic SSE4.1 implementation:

```
__m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i += 8)
{
    //  Load 8 16-bit ushorts.
    //  vi = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
    __m128i vi = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i));

    //  Convert to 32-bit integers
    //  vi0 = {a,0,b,0,c,0,d,0}
    //  vi1 = {e,0,f,0,g,0,h,0}
    __m128i vi0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(vi);
    __m128i vi1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(vi,vi));

    //  Convert to float
    __m128 vf0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi0);
    __m128 vf1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi1);

    //  Multiply
    vf0 = _mm_mul_ps(vf0,factor);
    vf1 = _mm_mul_ps(vf1,factor);

    //  Store
    _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 0,vf0);
    _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 4,vf1);
}
```

This assumes:

1. `source` and `destination` are both aligned to 16 bytes.
2. `W*H` is a multiple of 8.

It's possible to do better by further unrolling this loop. (see below)

---

The idea here is as follows:

1. Load 8 shorts into a single SSE register.
2. Split the register into two: One with the bottom 4 shorts and the other with the top 4 shorts.
3. Zero-extend both registers into 32-bit integers.
4. Convert them both to `float`s.
5. Multiply by the factor.
6. Store them into `destination`.

---

**EDIT :**

It's been a while since I've done this type of optimization, so I went ahead and unrolled the loops.

**Core i7 920 @ 3.5 GHz

Visual Studio 2012 - Release x64:**

```
Original Loop      : 4.374 seconds
Vectorize no unroll: 1.665
Vectorize unroll 2 : 1.416
```

Further unrolling resulted in diminishing returns.

Here's the test code:

```
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
using namespace std;


void default_loop(float *destination,const short* source,float value,int size){
    float factor = 1.0f / value; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int value = source[i];
        destination[i] = value*factor;
    }
}
void vectorize8_unroll1(float *destination,const short* source,float value,int size){
    __m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8)
    {
        //  Load 8 16-bit ushorts.
        __m128i vi = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i));

        //  Convert to 32-bit integers
        __m128i vi0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(vi);
        __m128i vi1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(vi,vi));

        //  Convert to float
        __m128 vf0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi0);
        __m128 vf1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi1);

        //  Multiply
        vf0 = _mm_mul_ps(vf0,factor);
        vf1 = _mm_mul_ps(vf1,factor);

        //  Store
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 0,vf0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 4,vf1);
    }
}
void vectorize8_unroll2(float *destination,const short* source,float value,int size){
    __m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16)
    {
        __m128i a0 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i + 0));
        __m128i a1 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i + 8));

        //  Split into two registers
        __m128i b0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a0,a0);
        __m128i b1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a1,a1);

        //  Convert to 32-bit integers
        a0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a0);
        b0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b0);
        a1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a1);
        b1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b1);

        //  Convert to float
        __m128 c0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a0);
        __m128 d0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(b0);
        __m128 c1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a1);
        __m128 d1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(b1);

        //  Multiply
        c0 = _mm_mul_ps(c0,factor);
        d0 = _mm_mul_ps(d0,factor);
        c1 = _mm_mul_ps(c1,factor);
        d1 = _mm_mul_ps(d1,factor);

        //  Store
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  0,c0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  4,d0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  8,c1);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 12,d1);
    }
}
void print_sum(const float *destination,int size){
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += destination[i];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}

int main(){

    int size = 8000;

    short *source       = (short*)_mm_malloc(size * sizeof(short), 16);
    float *destination  = (float*)_mm_malloc(size * sizeof(float), 16);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        source[i] = i;
    }

    float value = 1.1;

    int iterations = 1000000;
    clock_t start;

    //  Default Loop
    start = clock();
    for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
        default_loop(destination,source,value,size);
    }
    cout << (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    print_sum(destination,size);

    //  Vectorize 8, no unroll
    start = clock();
    for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
        vectorize8_unroll1(destination,source,value,size);
    }
    cout << (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    print_sum(destination,size);

    //  Vectorize 8, unroll 2
    start = clock();
    for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
        vectorize8_unroll2(destination,source,value,size);
    }
    cout << (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    print_sum(destination,size);

    _mm_free(source);
    _mm_free(destination);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that you'll need `#include <smmintrin.h>` for SSE4.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, at the end of the day this routine went from occupying 26% of runtime to 11%, which puts it within my timing window to perform it on each frame!

Comment: @Mystical : I mentioned you in my answer.  I some of your code with mine.  See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 9):

I believe I have the best answer.  My results are much faster than Mystical's.  They only require SSE2 but take advantage of SSE3, SSE4, AVX, and even AVX2 if available.  You don't have to change any code.  You only have to recompile.

I ran over three sizes: 8008, 64000, and 2560*1920 = 4915200.  I tried several different variations.  I list the most important ones below.  The function `vectorize8_unroll2` is mystical's function.  I made a improved version of his called `vectorize8_unroll2_parallel`. The function `vec16_loop_unroll2_fix` and `vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix` are my functions which I believe are better than mystical's.  These functions will automatically use AVX if you compile with AVX but work fine on SSE4 and even SSE2

Additionally, you wrote "W*H is always divisible by 8, most of the time W and H are divisible by 8".
So we can't assume W*H is divisible by 16 in all cases. Mystical's function  `vectorize8_unroll2`  has a bug when size is not a multiple of 16 (try size=8008 in his code and you will see what I mean).  My code has no such bug.

I'm using Ander Fog's vectorclass for the vectorization.  It's not a lib or dll file.  It's just a few header files.  I use OpenMP for the parallelization.  Here are some of the results:

```
Intel Xeon E5630 @2.53GHz (supports upto SSE4.2)    
size 8008, size2 8032, iterations 1000000

                        default_loop time: 7.935 seconds, diff 0.000000
                  vectorize8_unroll2 time: 1.875 seconds, diff 0.000000
              vec16_loop_unroll2_fix time: 1.878 seconds, diff 0.000000
         vectorize8_unroll2_parallel time: 1.253 seconds, diff 0.000000
     vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix time: 1.151 seconds, diff 0.000000

size 64000, size2 64000, iterations 100000
                        default_loop time: 6.387 seconds, diff 0.000000
                  vectorize8_unroll2 time: 1.875 seconds, diff 0.000000
              vec16_loop_unroll2_fix time: 2.195 seconds, diff 0.000000
         vectorize8_unroll2_parallel time: 0.439 seconds, diff 0.000000
     vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix time: 0.432 seconds, diff 0.000000

size 4915200, size2 4915200, iterations 1000
                        default_loop time: 5.125 seconds, diff 0.000000
                  vectorize8_unroll2 time: 3.496 seconds, diff 0.000000
              vec16_loop_unroll2_fix time: 3.490 seconds, diff 0.000000
         vectorize8_unroll2_parallel time: 3.119 seconds, diff 0.000000
     vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix time: 3.127 seconds, diff 0.000000
```

Edit: I added the results on a system with AVX using GCC at the end of this answer.

Below is the code.  The code only looks long because I do lots of cross checks and test many variations.  Download the vectorclass at 
http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass .  Copy the header files (vectorclass.h, instrset.h, vectorf128.h, vectorf256.h, vectorf256e.h, vectori128.h, vectori256.h, vectori256e.h) into the directory you compile from.  Add /D__SSE4_2__ under C++/CommandLine.  Compile in release mode. If you have a CPU with AVX then put /arch:AVX instead.  Add OpenMP support under C++ properites/languages.

```
In GCC
SSE4.2: g++ foo.cpp -o foo_gcc -O3 -mSSE4.2 -fopenmp
AVX: g++ foo.cpp -o foo_gcc -O3 -mavx -fopenmp
```

In the code below the function `vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel` requires the array be a multiple of 32.  You can change the array size to be a multiple of 32 (that's what size2 refers to) or if that's not possible you can just use the function `vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix` which has no such restriction.  It's just as fast anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vectorclass.h"
#include "omp.h"

#define ROUND_DOWN(x, s) ((x) & ~((s)-1))

inline void* aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t align) {
    void *result;
    #ifdef _MSC_VER 
    result = _aligned_malloc(size, align);
    #else 
     if(posix_memalign(&result, align, size)) result = 0;
    #endif
    return result;
}

inline void aligned_free(void *ptr) {
    #ifdef _MSC_VER 
        _aligned_free(ptr);
    #else 
      free(ptr);
    #endif

}

void default_loop(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size){
    float factor = 1.0f/value;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int value = source[i];
        destination[i] = value*factor;
    }
}


void default_loop_parallel(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size){
    float factor = 1.0f / value;
    #pragma omp parallel for  
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int value = source[i];
        destination[i] = value*factor;
    }
}

void vec8_loop(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8) {
    Vec8us vi = Vec8us().load(source + i);
    Vec4ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec4ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec4f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec4f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 4);
  }
}

void vec8_loop_unroll2(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16) {
    Vec8us vi = Vec8us().load(source + i);
    Vec4ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec4ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec4f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec4f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i + 0);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 4);

    Vec8us vi_new = Vec8us().load(source + i + 8);
    Vec4ui vi2 = extend_low(vi_new);
    Vec4ui vi3 = extend_high(vi_new);
    Vec4f vf2 = to_float(vi2);
    Vec4f vf3 = to_float(vi3);
    vf2*=factor;
    vf3*=factor;
    vf2.store(destination + i + 8);
    vf3.store(destination + i + 12);
  }
}

void vec8_loop_parallel(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8) {
    Vec8us vi = Vec8us().load(source + i);
    Vec4ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec4ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec4f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec4f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 4);
  }
}

void vec8_loop_unroll2_parallel(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16) {
    Vec8us vi = Vec8us().load(source + i);
    Vec4ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec4ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec4f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec4f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i + 0);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 4);

    Vec8us vi_new = Vec8us().load(source + i + 8);
    Vec4ui vi2 = extend_low(vi_new);
    Vec4ui vi3 = extend_high(vi_new);
    Vec4f vf2 = to_float(vi2);
    Vec4f vf3 = to_float(vi3);
    vf2*=factor;
    vf3*=factor;
    vf2.store(destination + i + 8);
    vf3.store(destination + i + 12);
  }
}

void vec16_loop(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16) {
    Vec16us vi = Vec16us().load(source + i);
    Vec8ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec8ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec8f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec8f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 8);
  }
}

void vec16_loop_unroll2(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 32) {
    Vec16us vi = Vec16us().load(source + i);

    Vec8ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec8ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec8f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec8f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i + 0);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 8);

    Vec16us vi_new = Vec16us().load(source + i + 16);

    Vec8ui vi2 = extend_low(vi_new);
    Vec8ui vi3 = extend_high(vi_new);
    Vec8f vf2 = to_float(vi2);
    Vec8f vf3 = to_float(vi3);
    vf2*=factor;
    vf3*=factor;
    vf2.store(destination + i + 16);
    vf3.store(destination + i + 24);

  }
}

void vec16_loop_unroll2_fix(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
    float factor=  1.0f/value;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i <ROUND_DOWN(size, 32); i += 32) {
    Vec16us vi = Vec16us().load(source + i);

    Vec8ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec8ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec8f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec8f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i + 0);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 8);

    Vec16us vi_new = Vec16us().load(source + i + 16);

    Vec8ui vi2 = extend_low(vi_new);
    Vec8ui vi3 = extend_high(vi_new);
    Vec8f vf2 = to_float(vi2);
    Vec8f vf3 = to_float(vi3);
    vf2*=factor;
    vf3*=factor;
    vf2.store(destination + i + 16);
    vf3.store(destination + i + 24);

    }
    for (; i < size; i++) {
        int value = source[i];
        destination[i] = value*factor;
    }

}

void vec16_loop_parallel(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
  float factor=  1.0f/value;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16) {
    Vec16us vi = Vec16us().load(source + i);
    Vec8ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
    Vec8ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
    Vec8f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
    Vec8f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
    vf0*=factor;
    vf1*=factor;
    vf0.store(destination + i);
    vf1.store(destination + i + 8);
  }
}

void vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
    float factor=  1.0f/value;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 32) {
        Vec16us vi = Vec16us().load(source + i); 
        Vec8ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
        Vec8ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
        Vec8f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
        Vec8f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
        vf0*=factor;
        vf1*=factor;
        vf0.store(destination + i + 0);
        vf1.store(destination + i + 8);

        Vec16us vi_new = Vec16us().load(source + i + 16);
        Vec8ui vi2 = extend_low(vi_new);
        Vec8ui vi3 = extend_high(vi_new);
        Vec8f vf2 = to_float(vi2);
        Vec8f vf3 = to_float(vi3);
        vf2*=factor;
        vf3*=factor;
        vf2.store(destination + i + 16);
        vf3.store(destination + i + 24);
    }
}

void vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size) {
    float factor=  1.0f/value;
    int i = 0;  
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i=0; i <ROUND_DOWN(size, 32); i += 32) {
        Vec16us vi = Vec16us().load(source + i);  
        Vec8ui vi0 = extend_low(vi);
        Vec8ui vi1 = extend_high(vi);
        Vec8f vf0 = to_float(vi0);
        Vec8f vf1 = to_float(vi1);
        vf0*=factor;
        vf1*=factor;
        vf0.store(destination + i + 0);
        vf1.store(destination + i + 8);

        Vec16us vi_new = Vec16us().load(source + i + 16); 
        Vec8ui vi2 = extend_low(vi_new);
        Vec8ui vi3 = extend_high(vi_new);
        Vec8f vf2 = to_float(vi2);
        Vec8f vf3 = to_float(vi3);
        vf2*=factor;
        vf3*=factor;
        vf2.store(destination + i + 16);
        vf3.store(destination + i + 24);

    }

    for(int i = ROUND_DOWN(size, 32); i < size; i++) {
        int value = source[i];
        destination[i] = value*factor;
    }

}

void vectorize8_unroll1(float *destination,const unsigned short* source,float value,int size){
    __m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8)
    {
        //  Load 8 16-bit ushorts.
        __m128i vi = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i));

        //  Convert to 32-bit integers
        __m128i vi0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(vi);
        __m128i vi1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(vi,vi));

        //  Convert to float
        __m128 vf0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi0);
        __m128 vf1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi1);

        //  Multiply
        vf0 = _mm_mul_ps(vf0,factor);
        vf1 = _mm_mul_ps(vf1,factor);

        //  Store
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 0,vf0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 4,vf1);
    }
}

void vectorize8_unroll2(float *destination,const unsigned short* source,float value,int size){
    __m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16)
    {
        __m128i a0 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i + 0));
        __m128i a1 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i + 8));

        //  Split into two registers
        __m128i b0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a0,a0);
        __m128i b1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a1,a1);

        //  Convert to 32-bit integers
        a0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a0);
        b0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b0);
        a1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a1);
        b1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b1);

        //  Convert to float
        __m128 c0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a0);
        __m128 d0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(b0);
        __m128 c1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a1);
        __m128 d1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(b1);

        //  Multiply
        c0 = _mm_mul_ps(c0,factor);
        d0 = _mm_mul_ps(d0,factor);
        c1 = _mm_mul_ps(c1,factor);
        d1 = _mm_mul_ps(d1,factor);

        //  Store
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  0,c0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  4,d0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  8,c1);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 12,d1);
    }
}

void vectorize8_unroll1_parallel(float *destination,const unsigned short* source,float value,int size){
    __m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8)
    {
        //  Load 8 16-bit ushorts.
        __m128i vi = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i));

        //  Convert to 32-bit integers
        __m128i vi0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(vi);
        __m128i vi1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(vi,vi));

        //  Convert to float
        __m128 vf0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi0);
        __m128 vf1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi1);

        //  Multiply
        vf0 = _mm_mul_ps(vf0,factor);
        vf1 = _mm_mul_ps(vf1,factor);

        //  Store
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 0,vf0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 4,vf1);
    }
}



void vectorize8_unroll2_parallel(float *destination,const unsigned short* source,float value,int size){
    __m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 16)
    {
        __m128i a0 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i + 0));
        __m128i a1 = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i + 8));

        //  Split into two registers
        __m128i b0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a0,a0);
        __m128i b1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a1,a1);

        //  Convert to 32-bit integers
        a0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a0);
        b0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b0);
        a1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a1);
        b1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b1);

        //  Convert to float
        __m128 c0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a0);
        __m128 d0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(b0);
        __m128 c1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a1);
        __m128 d1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(b1);

        //  Multiply
        c0 = _mm_mul_ps(c0,factor);
        d0 = _mm_mul_ps(d0,factor);
        c1 = _mm_mul_ps(c1,factor);
        d1 = _mm_mul_ps(d1,factor);

        //  Store
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  0,c0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  4,d0);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i +  8,c1);
        _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 12,d1);
    }
}

void copy_arrays(float* a, float*b, const int size) {
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}

float compare_arrays(float* a, float*b, const int size) {
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        float diff = a[i] - b[i];
        if(diff!=0)  {
            printf("i %d, a[i] %f, b[i] %f, diff %f\n", i, a[i], b[i], diff);
            break;
        }
        sum += diff;
    }
    return sum;
}

void randomize_array(unsigned short* a, const int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        float r = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        a[i] = (int)(65536*r);
    }
}

void run(int size, int iterations) {
    int rd = ROUND_DOWN(size, 32);
    int size2 = rd == size ? size : rd + 32;
    float value = 1.1f;

    printf("size %d, size2 %d, iterations %d\n", size, size2, iterations);
    unsigned short* source = (unsigned short*)aligned_malloc(size2*sizeof(short), 16);
    float* destination = (float*)aligned_malloc(size2*sizeof(float), 16);
    float* destination_old = (float*)aligned_malloc(size2*sizeof(float), 16);
    float* destination_ref = (float*)aligned_malloc(size2*sizeof(float), 16);

    void (*fp[16])(float *destination, const unsigned short* source, float value, int size);
    fp[0] = default_loop;
    fp[1] = vec8_loop;
    fp[2] = vec8_loop_unroll2;
    fp[3] = vec16_loop;
    fp[4] = vec16_loop_unroll2;
    fp[5] = vec16_loop_unroll2_fix;
    fp[6] = vectorize8_unroll1;
    fp[7] = vectorize8_unroll2;

    fp[8] = default_loop_parallel;
    fp[9] = vec8_loop_parallel;
    fp[10] = vec8_loop_unroll2_parallel;
    fp[11] = vec16_loop_parallel;
    fp[12] = vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel;
    fp[13] = vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix;
    fp[14] = vectorize8_unroll1_parallel;
    fp[15] = vectorize8_unroll2_parallel;

    char* func_str[] = {"default_loop", "vec8_loop", "vec8_loop_unrool2", "vec16_loop", "vec16_loop_unroll2", "vec16_loop_unroll2_fix", "vectorize8_unroll1", "vectorize8_unroll2",
        "default_loop_parallel", "vec8_loop_parallel", "vec8_loop_unroll2_parallel","vec16_loop_parallel", "vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel", "vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix",
        "vectorize8_unroll1_parallel", "vectorize8_unroll2_parallel"};

    randomize_array(source, size2);

    copy_arrays(destination_old, destination_ref, size);
    fp[0](destination_ref, source, value, size);

    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        copy_arrays(destination_old, destination, size);
        double dtime = omp_get_wtime();
        for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
            fp[i](destination, source, value, size);
        }
        dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
        float diff = compare_arrays(destination, destination_ref, size);
        printf("%40s time: %.3f seconds, diff %f\n", func_str[i], dtime, diff);
    }
    printf("\n");
    aligned_free(source);
    aligned_free(destination);
    aligned_free(destination_old);
    aligned_free(destination_ref);
}
int main() {
    run(8008, 1000000); 
    run(64000, 100000);
    run(2560*1920, 1000);
}
```

Results Using GCC on a system with AVX.  GCC automatically parallelizes the loop (Visual Studio fails due to the short but works if you try int).  You gain very little with hand written vectorization code.  However, using multiple threads can help depending upon the array size.  For the small array size 8008 OpenMP gives a worse result.  However, for the larger array size 128000 using OpenMP gives much better resutls.  For the largest array size 4915200 it's entirely memory bound and OpenMP does not help.

```
i7-2600k @ 4.4GHz
size 8008, size2 8032, iterations 1000000
                        default_loop time: 1.319 seconds, diff 0.000000          
              vec16_loop_unroll2_fix time: 1.167 seconds, diff 0.000000
                  vectorize8_unroll2 time: 1.227 seconds, diff 0.000000                
         vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel time: 1.528 seconds, diff 0.000000
         vectorize8_unroll2_parallel time: 1.381 seconds, diff 0.000000

size 128000, size2 128000, iterations 100000
                        default_loop time: 2.902 seconds, diff 0.000000                     
              vec16_loop_unroll2_fix time: 2.838 seconds, diff 0.000000
                  vectorize8_unroll2 time: 2.844 seconds, diff 0.000000         
     vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix time: 0.706 seconds, diff 0.000000
         vectorize8_unroll2_parallel time: 0.672 seconds, diff 0.000000

size 4915200, size2 4915200, iterations 1000
                        default_loop time: 2.313 seconds, diff 0.000000
              vec16_loop_unroll2_fix time: 2.309 seconds, diff 0.000000    
                  vectorize8_unroll2 time: 2.318 seconds, diff 0.000000                
     vec16_loop_unroll2_parallel_fix time: 2.353 seconds, diff 0.000000         
         vectorize8_unroll2_parallel time: 2.349 seconds, diff 0.000000
```

Comment: Wow this is a really detailed response. I will try to take a look into it in the next few days.

Comment: The performance difference I see is not nearly as pronounced for single threaded operation, but I think you need the points a lot more than @Mysticial ...

Comment: That's because I used the algorithm of @Mystical and adapted it to the Vectorclass.  My main contribution was adding threading since you wrote "on a multicore x86 machine" but maybe you just wanted it to be thread friendly.  Anyway, give the bounty to Mystical.  He deserves it more.  I prefer to earn my points not be given them because someone thinks I need them.

Comment: It was also a lot of work and I think it was good work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Using SSE intrinsics, on my machine [Quad Core Athlon, 3.3GHz, 16GB of RAM], and `g++ -O2` optimisation [1] gives about 2.5-3x speed up. I also wrote a function to do the same thing in inline assembler, but it's not noticeably faster (again, this applies on my machine, feel free to run on other machines).

I tried a variety of sizes of H * W, and it all gives approximately the same results.

[1] Using `g++ -O3` gives the same time for all four functions, as apparently `-O3` enables "automatically vectorise code". So the whole thing was a bit of a waste of time assuming your compiler supports similar auto-vectorisation functionality.

**Results**

```
convert_naive                  sum=4373.98 t=7034751 t/n=7.03475
convert_naive                  sum=4373.98 t=7266738 t/n=7.26674
convert_naive                  sum=4373.98 t=7006154 t/n=7.00615
convert_naive                  sum=4373.98 t=6815329 t/n=6.81533
convert_naive                  sum=4373.98 t=6820318 t/n=6.82032
convert_unroll4                sum=4373.98 t=8103193 t/n=8.10319
convert_unroll4                sum=4373.98 t=7276156 t/n=7.27616
convert_unroll4                sum=4373.98 t=7028181 t/n=7.02818
convert_unroll4                sum=4373.98 t=7074258 t/n=7.07426
convert_unroll4                sum=4373.98 t=7081518 t/n=7.08152
convert_sse_intrinsic          sum=4373.98 t=3377290 t/n=3.37729
convert_sse_intrinsic          sum=4373.98 t=3227018 t/n=3.22702
convert_sse_intrinsic          sum=4373.98 t=3007898 t/n=3.0079
convert_sse_intrinsic          sum=4373.98 t=3253366 t/n=3.25337
convert_sse_intrinsic          sum=4373.98 t=5576068 t/n=5.57607
convert_sse_inlineasm          sum=4373.98 t=3470887 t/n=3.47089
convert_sse_inlineasm          sum=4373.98 t=2838492 t/n=2.83849
convert_sse_inlineasm          sum=4373.98 t=2828556 t/n=2.82856
convert_sse_inlineasm          sum=4373.98 t=2789052 t/n=2.78905
convert_sse_inlineasm          sum=4373.98 t=3176522 t/n=3.17652
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstring>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>


#define W 1000
#define H 1000

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

void convert_naive(short *source, float *destination)
{
    float factor=  1.0f/32767;
    for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i++)
    {
    int value = source[i];
    destination[i] = value*factor;
    }
}


void convert_unroll4(short *source, float *destination)
{
    float factor=  1.0f/32767;
    for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i+=4)
    {
    int v1 = source[i];
    int v2 = source[i+1];
    int v3 = source[i+2];
    int v4 = source[i+3];
    destination[i]   = v1*factor;
    destination[i+1] = v2*factor;
    destination[i+2] = v3*factor;
    destination[i+3] = v4*factor;
    }
}


void convert_sse_intrinsic(short *source, float *destination)
{
    __m128 factor =  { 1.0f/32767, 1.0f/32767, 1.0f/32767, 1.0f/32767 };
    __m64 zero1 =  { 0,0 };
    __m128i zero2 =  { 0,0 };
    __m64 *ps = reinterpret_cast<__m64 *>(source);
    __m128 *pd = reinterpret_cast<__m128 *>(destination);
    for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i+=4)
    {
    __m128i value = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(_mm_set_epi64(zero1, *ps), zero2);
    value = _mm_srai_epi32(_mm_slli_epi32(value, 16), 16);
    __m128  fval  = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(value);
    *pd = _mm_mul_ps(fval, factor);   // destination[0,1,2,3] = value[0,1,2,3] * factor;
    pd++;
    ps++;
    }
}

void convert_sse_inlineasm(short *source, float *destination)
{
    __m128 factor =  { 1.0f/32767, 1.0f/32767, 1.0f/32767, 1.0f/32767 };
    __asm__ __volatile__(
    "\t pxor       %%xmm1, %%xmm1\n"
    "\t movaps     %3, %%xmm2\n"
    "\t mov        $0, %%rax\n"
    "1:"
    "\t movq       (%1, %%rax), %%xmm0\n"
    "\t movq       8(%1, %%rax), %%xmm3\n"
    "\t movq       16(%1, %%rax), %%xmm4\n"
    "\t movq       24(%1, %%rax), %%xmm5\n"
    "\t punpcklwd  %%xmm1, %%xmm0\n"
    "\t pslld      $16, %%xmm0\n"
    "\t psrad      $16, %%xmm0\n"
    "\t cvtdq2ps   %%xmm0, %%xmm0\n"
    "\t mulps      %%xmm2, %%xmm0\n"
    "\t punpcklwd  %%xmm1, %%xmm3\n"
    "\t pslld      $16, %%xmm3\n"
    "\t psrad      $16, %%xmm3\n"
    "\t cvtdq2ps   %%xmm3, %%xmm3\n"
    "\t mulps      %%xmm2, %%xmm3\n"
    "\t punpcklwd  %%xmm1, %%xmm4\n"
    "\t pslld      $16, %%xmm4\n"
    "\t psrad      $16, %%xmm4\n"
    "\t cvtdq2ps   %%xmm4, %%xmm4\n"
    "\t mulps      %%xmm2, %%xmm4\n"
    "\t punpcklwd  %%xmm1, %%xmm5\n"
    "\t pslld      $16, %%xmm5\n"
    "\t psrad      $16, %%xmm5\n"
    "\t cvtdq2ps   %%xmm5, %%xmm5\n"
    "\t mulps      %%xmm2, %%xmm5\n"
    "\t movaps     %%xmm0, (%0, %%rax, 2)\n"
    "\t movaps     %%xmm3, 16(%0, %%rax, 2)\n"
    "\t movaps     %%xmm4, 32(%0, %%rax, 2)\n"
    "\t movaps     %%xmm5, 48(%0, %%rax, 2)\n"
    "\t addq       $32, %%rax\n"
    "\t cmpq       %2, %%rax\n"
    "\t jbe        1b\n"
    : /* no outputs */ 
    : "r" (destination), "r" (source), "i"(sizeof(*source) * H * W), "m"(factor):
      "rax", "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm3");
}




short inbuffer[W * H] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
float outbuffer[W * H + 16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
#ifdef DEBUG
float outbuffer2[W * H];
#endif


typedef void (*func)(short *source, float *destination);

struct BmEntry
{
    const char *name;
    func  fn;
};

void bm(BmEntry& e)
{
    memset(outbuffer, 0, sizeof(outbuffer));
    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    e.fn(inbuffer, outbuffer);
    t = rdtsc() - t; 

    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < W * H; i++)
    {
    sum += outbuffer[i]; 
    }

#if DEBUG
    convert_naive(inbuffer, outbuffer2);
    for(int i = 0; i < W * H; i++)
    {
    if (outbuffer[i] != outbuffer2[i])
    {
        std::cout << i << ":: " << inbuffer[i] << ": " 
              << outbuffer[i] << " != " << outbuffer2[i] 
              << std::endl;
    }
    }
#endif

    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(30) << e.name << " sum=" << sum << " t=" << t << 
    " t/n=" << (double)t / (W * H) << std::endl;
}


#define BM(x) { #x, x }


BmEntry table[] = 
{
    BM(convert_naive),
    BM(convert_unroll4),
    BM(convert_sse_intrinsic),
    BM(convert_sse_inlineasm),
};


int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < W * H; i++)
    {
    inbuffer[i] = (short)i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[i]); i++)
    {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        bm(table[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The VS2012 doesn't vectorize this loop. I'm going to take a look into this implementation in the next few days. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

No sure if the condition expression in the loop is evaluated only once.
You can try:

```
float factor=  1.0f/value;
for (int i = 0, count = W*H; i < count; ++i)//25% of time is spent doing this
{
    int value = source[i];//short -> int
    destination[i] = value*factor;//int->float
}
```

Comment: If `W` and `H` are compile time constants, the compiler should do the multiplication, and there should be no impact.  If they aren't, it depends on the optimization level, and probably the types and how `destination` is defined.  Nominally, it's trivial to see that the loop doesn't modify `W` or `H`, and so hoist the multiplication out of the loop.  Depending on circumstances, however, the compiler _may_ have to consider the possibility that `destination[i]` is an alias for `W` or `H`, in which case, it cannot hoist.

Comment: also, depending on the circumstances, there might be a possibility that `W` and `H` are modified 'externally', e.g. by another thread. I'm not sure if the compiler is allowed to assume that they remain constant during the loop, independently of the optimization level ...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid answer, don't take it as it, but I'm actually wondering how would the code behave by using a 256k look-up table. (basically a 'short to float' table with 65536 entries).

A CoreI7 has about 8 megabytes of cache I believe, so the look-up table would fit in the data cache.

I really wonder how that would impact the performance :)

Answer (score 2):

and You can use OpenMP to hire every core of your CPU, and it is simple just do as following:

```
#include <omp.h>
float factor=  1.0f/value;
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i++)//25% of time is spent doing this
{
    int value = source[i];//ushort -> int
    destination[i] = value*factor;//int*float->float
}
```

here is the result based on previous program, just add the like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
 ...
}
```

and then here is the result

```
beta@beta-PC ~
$ g++ -o opt.exe opt.c -msse4.1 -fopenmp

beta@beta-PC ~
$ opt
0.748
2.90873e+007
0.484
2.90873e+007
0.796
2.90873e+007


beta@beta-PC ~
$ g++ -o opt.exe opt.c -msse4.1 -O3


beta@beta-PC ~
$ opt
1.404
2.90873e+007
1.404
2.90873e+007
1.404
2.90873e+007
```

. .

result shows 100% improvment with openmp. Visual C++ supports openmp too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to approximate the expression

```
float factor = 1.0f/value;
```

by an fraction `numerator/denomitator` where both `numerator` and `denominator` are `int`s. This can be done to the precision you need in your application like

```
int denominator = 10000;
int numerator = factor * denominator;
```

Then you can do your computation in integer arithmetics like

```
int value = source[i];
destination[i] = (value * numerator) / numerator;
```

You have to take care of overflows, perhaps you need to switch to `long` (or even `long long` on 64bit systems) for the calculation.

Comment: That only (possibly) helps if the result doesn't have to be float anyway - there are several audioprocessing functions out there that want a `-1.0 .. 1.0` range for audio, rather than `-32768 .. 32767`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You're right, I probably misread the question. I'll leave the answer anyway perhaps it is useful for other situations ...

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying your answer as such is poor, it's just a limitation.