# Is there a correct way to measure performance when writing low-level code?

Tags: c, x86-64, performance-testing

I am writing speed optimizations for low-level C/x64 code and I am wondering if there is any standard way of measuring which choice is faster reliably.

My current technique when comparing technique A and B involves repeating A a few hundred times, than repeating B the same about of time, and comparing the mean time taken by each. I then repeat this across a few dozen examples, and then compare the *mean* mean of each technique. (I do the same for the mean min)

Unfortunately there seems to be some issues with this method. For example if I consider a 3rd technique to test, but in fact use B, this second run of B will be almost systematically faster (cache effects?), faster enough to beat A.

Also are there more appropriate techniques for profiling JIT-ed code?

Comment: You could look at the assembler code generated.

Comment: I am the one generating assembly code ;)

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick.

```
static unsigned long long rdtsctime() {
    unsigned int eax, edx;
    unsigned long long val;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc":"=a"(eax), "=d"(edx));
    val = edx;
    val = val << 32;
    val += eax;
    return val;
}
```

Call it once to get the current time, then again and subtract the first value to get elapsed time (in cycles).

Comment: Some years ago, Intel redefined the `rdtsc` instruction to return real time, not processor cycles. Using it to measure code performance without compensating for this will return inaccurate results when the processor speeds up or slows down, as it does for various reasons such as heat and work load.

Comment: Indeed, there are a number of reason I don't use rdtsc anymore.  One trivial one is that the code above won't work in with Visual Studio 64bit (you have to use an intrinsic) but there are more serious reason I think explained pretty well on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter#Use

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question.  I have been wondering myself what the best way to measure performance is.  I don't think you will find one simple answer.  What I usually do is make a function pointer to different variations of the function and then time each function over several iterations.  I used a function from OpenMP (even if don't use any threading) `omp_get_wtime()` to do the timing.  For example, let's assume
I have two variations of a function, `foo_v1` and `foo_v2`, that take an array `a` with a number of elements `n`.  A generic way I might use to measure the performance of these two functions would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
void foo_v1(float *a, const int n) {
   //    
}
void foo_v2(float *a, const int n) {
   //    
}
int main() {
    const int n = 1000;
    float *a = new float[n];
    void (*fp[2])(float *a, const int n);
    fp[0] = foo_v1;
    fp[1] = foo_v2;
    const int nrepeat = 1000; //some number large so that the functions take at least a second to finish
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        double dtime = omp_get_wtime();
        for(int i=0; i<nrepeat; i++) {    
            fp[j](a, n);
        }
        dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
        printf("time in seconds %f\n", dtime);
     }
     delete[] a;
}
```

You can see an example of where I did this with 16 function variations in a bounty question here.
[Speedup a short to float cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031149/speedup-a-short-to-float-cast/16362367#16362367)

I'm not sure how good this method for comparing performance is but it's the one I have been using.