# Short to Float and viceversa conversion using NEON SIMD

Tags: android, arm, simd, neon

I am processing audio buffers in Android, the setup I have is as follows:

1. get system callback with a short buffer
2. convert short buffer to float buffer
3. do some DSP with float buffer
4. convert float buffer to short buffer
5. deliver short buffer to system

I want to reduce the latency of steps 2 and 4, the short to float and float to short conversions. (leaving aside the latency in the 3- DSP since I will take care of that later).

So, I would like to use NEON SIMD to calculate multiple values at a time.

What I currently have for 2 and 4 is the following code:

```
#define CONV16BIT 32768
#define CONVMYFLT (1./32768.)
static int i;
float * floatBuffer;
short * shortInBuffer;
short * shortOutBuffer;

...(malloc and init buffers method)

...(inside callback) 
//2- short to float
for(i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    floatBuffer[i] = (float) (shortInBuffer[i] * CONVMYFLT);
}

...(do dsp)

//4- float to short
for(i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    shortOutBuffer[i] = (short) (floatBuffer[i] * CONV16BIT);
}
```

I believe that the steps I need for taking advantage of NEON are:

(for the short to float part)

1. Load the 16-bit shorts form short buffer
2. Convert them to 32-bit integers
3. Convert them to float
4. Multiply them by CONVMYFLT
5. Store them into float buffer

Found this info in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031149/speedup-a-short-to-float-cast) (selected answer)

```
__m128 factor = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / value);
for (int i = 0; i < W*H; i += 8)
{
    //  Load 8 16-bit ushorts.
    //  vi = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
    __m128i vi = _mm_load_si128((const __m128i*)(source + i));

    //  Convert to 32-bit integers
    //  vi0 = {a,0,b,0,c,0,d,0}
    //  vi1 = {e,0,f,0,g,0,h,0}
    __m128i vi0 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(vi);
    __m128i vi1 = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(vi,vi));

    //  Convert to float
    __m128 vf0 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi0);
    __m128 vf1 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(vi1);

    //  Multiply
    vf0 = _mm_mul_ps(vf0,factor);
    vf1 = _mm_mul_ps(vf1,factor);

    //  Store
    _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 0,vf0);
    _mm_store_ps(destination + i + 4,vf1);
}
```

However this is SIMD for intel SSE4.1 not for NEON.

**What would be the equivalent implementation for NEON in Android?** (had a hard time understanding the NEON intrinsics)

**Update 1**
From the answer of fsheikh I was able to build this:
- I was able to get int16_t from the system callback
- and all my buffer sizes are multiple of 8:

```
int16x8_t i16v;
int32x4_t i32vl, i32vh;
float32x4_t f32vl, f32vh;
for(i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += 8) {
    //load 8 16-bit lanes on vector
    i16v = vld1q_s16((const int16x8_t*) int16_t_inBuffer[i]);
    // convert into 32-bit signed integer
    i32vl = vmovl_s16 (i16v);
    i32vh = vmovl_s16 (vzipq_s16(i16v, i16v).val[0]);
    //convert to 32-bit float
    f32vl = vcvtq_f32_s32(i32vl);
    f32vh = vcvtq_f32_s32(i32vh);
    //multiply by scalar
    f32vl = vmulq_n_f32(f32vl, CONVMYFLT);
    f32vh = vmulq_n_f32(f32vh, CONVMYFLT);
    //store in float buffer
    vst1q_f32(floatBuffer[i], f32vl);
    vst1q_f32(floatBuffer[i + 4], f32vh);
}
```

**Should this work right?**
I have doubts over i should use the low or high part of the interleaved vector returned by vmovl_s16:

i32vh = vmovl_s16 (vzipq_s1 6(i16v, i16v).val[ 0 ]); or

i32vh = vmovl_s16 (vzipq_s16(i16v, i16v).val[ 1 ]);

Comment: Why bother when a competent compiler will easily autovectorize this?

Comment: @EOF since I have a bottle neck I want to measure speed of the loop between the c implementation and NEON intrinsics, I have read various posts where it's suggested one or the other should be faster or not, I want to check this.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have the SSE version, you can use the GCC ARM NEON intrinsics list to port SSE macros to NEON. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html

So for example:

```
// Load unsigned short
uint16x4_t vld1_u16 (const uint16_t *)

// Convert to unsigned int
uint32x4_t vmovl_u16 (uint16x4_t) 

// Convert to float
float32x4_t vcvtq_f32_s32 (int32x4_t)

// Multiply floats with a scalar
float32x4_t vmulq_n_f32 (float32x4_t, float32_t) 

// Store results into a float buffer
void vst1q_f32 (float32_t *, float32x4_t)
```

Comment: based on your answer I updated the question, would you check it out? *since I have buffers that are multiple of 8 and are signed I decided to use int16x8_t

Comment: @alexm From what I recall there is something like vmov_s16(vget_low_s16(i16v)) that you can use to remove ambiguity with interleaved vector elements. P.S: if the answer to original question was useful can you please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: that is right, I have just updated my code. (will read more about the intrinsics for NEON)